# sequelize rollback not working with promise.all

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

sequelize transaction not rolling back when I use Promise.all with "looping update"

I'm using PostgreSQL with sequelize and the code below works fine if there is no error.

```
return db.transaction(t => {
 let promises = [];
 promises.push(
  valuesToUpdate.map(item => {
   return db.models.TableToUpdate.update(
    {
     prop1: item.val1,
     prop2: item.val2,
     prop3: item.val3,
     prop4: item.val4
    }
   );
  })
 );

 return Promise.all(promises)
  .then(res => {
   return h.response().code(201);
    })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
         });
 });
```

Expected result: When there is an error in any of the updated values, sequelize should roll back everything in that transaction

Actual result: When there is an error in any of the updated values, sequelize commits correct values, but does not commit values with error (like not null violation, etc.). I don't want this. Also if there is an error, the catch block is invoked, but sequelize still does not roll back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There needs to be a catch at the transaction level.  Here's the structure I use:

```
 sequelizeDB.transaction(function (t) {                                  
    ...
    promises.push(newPromise1);
    ...
    promises.push(newPromise2);
    ...
    return Promise.all(promises);
 }).then(function () {
    console.log("SUCCESS!!! (will commit)");
    next(); 
 }).catch(function (err) {
    console.log("FAILURE !!! (will rollback)");
    return next(err);
 });
```

Comment: Thanks! it works now! My problem was that I was catching the promise.all itself not the transaction.